# Tasker | Keyboard | how to bring down keyboard in Dropbox?

Tags: keyboard, tasker, dropbox

Dropbox for Android does not have a "*do not automatically open keyboard*" option. So we'll have to do this via **Tasker**.

Keyboard for Dropbox only pops up when your opening a word-doc (like a .txt file) and continues to do so when re-focusing back to Dropbox while the word-doc is still open regardless of the user bringing it down.

In Tasker how can we bring Keyboard down when ever dropbox is put to focus? (and/or when ever Dropbox is launched).